# у меня 3 батон для получения данных из ком порта а 4 наоборот для ввода но почему-то 4 не хочет работать

Tags: c#, com-port

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var file = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Шамиль\\Desktop\\Lab4\\Lab4\\Lab4.txt");
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        
        listBox2.Items.Add(file.ReadToEnd());
        file.Close();

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var file = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Учёба\\Proga C#\\Lab4\\Lab4\\Lab4.txt");
                     foreach (var item in lbPortData.Items)
                         {
        file.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                        }
        file.Close();
```

Comment: "Батон" - это хлеб, в магазине продается. А так, "не работает" - вот вам такое скажут, как программисту, вы как поступите? Поймете о чем речь? Поймете в чем проблема? Думаю нет. А почему вы, программист, говорите "не работает"? Я лично считаю это хамством. Не работает как? Программа закрывается? Компьютер выключается? Пробки выбивает? Током бьет? Что?

Comment: В пути `C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Учёба\\...` Вы забыли написать, что Вы Шамиль )))

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Evgeniyz, я в программировании совсем недавно, так что не судите строго)